# Compare Array of Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'd like to make this array:

```
[
   {main: "material", value: "blend"}, 
   {main: "material", value: "synthetic"}, 
   {main: "style", value: "curl"}, 
   {main: "style", value: "bob"}, 
   {main: "material", value: "premium"}
]
```

to this:

```
{
 material: ["blend", "synthetic", "premium"], 
 style: ["curl", "bob"]
}
```

I used two "for-loops" but it didn't work out well:( Quite newbie in Javascript

Comment: Post the JavaScript as a [mcve] so we can fix it. We don't write JavaScript from scratch.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with _object comparison_. Looks more like you want to [_reduce_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your array by collecting like-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to have that result

```js
const data = [{
  main: "material",
  value: "blend"
}, {
  main: "material",
  value: "synthetic"
}, {
  main: "style",
  value: "curl"
}, {
  main: "style",
  value: "bob"
}, {
  main: "material",
  value: "premium"
}]

const finalResut = data.reduce((result, currentData) => {
  const {
    main,
    value
  } = currentData
  if (!result[main]) {
    result[main] = []
  }
  result[main].push(value)
  return result
}, {})

console.log(finalResut)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using For Loop Here's how to do it. You Can Also Use `reduce` function as @Nick Vu Suggested.

```js
var array = [
   {main: "material", value: "blend"}, 
   {main: "material", value: "synthetic"}, 
   {main: "style", value: "curl"}, 
   {main: "style", value: "bob"}, 
   {main: "material", value: "premium"}
]
var newArray = {material:[],style:[]}
for (var i =0;i<array.length;i++){
    if (array[i].main == "material")
    {newArray.material.push(array[i].value)}
    else
    {newArray.style.push(array[i].value)}}
console.log(newArray)
```